# Batch xcopy not working

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, xcopy

I have a very simply batch file that I am trying to execute. The premise of it is simple: for every user, copy a folder and all its contents into another folder. However, upon executing I am unsuccessful. I do not get any error messages and it exits out immediately. I have ran the xcopy command itself with success, so this leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with the for loop. My knowledge with command prompt is relatively limited, so please pardon my ignorance in regards to the subject. Thanks for any help!

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /ad C:\Users') do xcopy C:\Folder "C:\Users\%a\AppData\Roaming\Folder" /f /j /s /w /y
```

Comment: Is `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /ad C:\Users')` any different from `for /d %a in (C:\Users\*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me from the command line (replacing `xcopy` with `echo xcopy`).  From a batch file, though, you'll need to double your `%` signs, so make sure you're using `%%a` instead of `%a`.

Comment: Bingo. This was it. Thanks so much for your help!